# sqlalchemy running much slower and causing more blocking than pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Based on warning messages from python, we recently changed our sql connections to sqlalchemy from pyodbc (sp's, read/write/insert).  We immediately saw a degradation in performance, and longer locking/blocking than before (particularly schema-M locks).  Are we using the engine correctly?  Has anyone else noticed a difference in speed or blocking?

#new alchemy connection/engine:

```
conn = create_engine(connstr)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=conn)
session = Session()

try:
     session.execute(sqlt)
     session.commit()
except Exception as ex:
     rc = ex
     session.rollback()
finally:
     session.close()
     conn.dispose()
return rc
```

#old pyodbc method:

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
    except:
        cursor.rollback()
    else:
        conn.commit()        
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: you do understand  that sqlalchemz is an ORM and select would look like https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html#simple-select

Comment: What were the "warning messages from python" you were getting?

Comment: @GordThompson like this: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Have you tried using `conn = create_engine(connstr, fast_executemany=True)` ?

Comment: @GordThompson, no we haven't.  I will try that.

Comment: @nbk, we want to pass our own sql queries to the engine...